# Questions of The Extension of Field

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Let $E_i (i=1, 2)$ be subfields of $K$ containing the subfield $F$, and $[E_i : F] < \infty$. If $E$ is the subfield of $K$ generated by $E_1$ and $E_2$, then $[E:F] \leqslant [E_1 : F][E_2 : F]$.

Could you give me some hint?
In fact, according to $[E:F] = [E : E_1][E_1 : F]$, I know we need to prove $[E:E_1]\leqslant [E_2: F]$, but what should I do next?

Comment: Do you mean subfield?

Comment: @MatteoIaccarino, of course sir.

Comment: @MatteoIaccarino Not entirely, I did see his approach, but I prefer to tackle it through the line of questioning that I proposed.

Comment: Please edit your post to replace "subdomain" by "subfield" everywhere, and "$E$ is a..." by "$E$ is the...", and choose a more descriptive title.

Comment: Actually, [the accepted answer to] the post linked by Matteo *does* answer your question: instead of writing "$\{a_ib_j\mid 1\le i\le n, 1\le j\le m\}$ is a spanning set" (of $E$ over $F$), simply write : "$\{b_j\mid1\le j\le m\}$ is a spanning set of $E$ over $E_1$", but don't change any word in the proof.